# Adicionar campo ao clicar em botão

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto de cadastro de clientes, em um formulário usando PrimeFaces eu gostaria de ao clicar em um botão e com isso fazer aparecer um inputText, caso clique de novo, outro aparece e assim por diante.
Isso é possível com jsf e primefaces?

A ideia é que esse campo adicionado corresponda a um objeto do tipo Login que é relacionado com `@OneToMany` do objeto Cliente

Comment: Você quer fazer isso dinamicamente ou com uma quantidade de campos definidos?

Comment: Tanto faz, o limite de campos pode sim ser pré-definido.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não existe um componente do `Primefaces` específico para isso.

Uma maneria de fazer isso é você usar o componente `<p:dataTable>`:

```
 <p:dataTable id="tabelaLogin" value="#{seu_bean.listaDeLogins}" var="login">
        <p:column headerText="Login">
               <h:inputText value="#{login.username}"/>
         </p:column>
   </p:dataTable>
<p:commandButton value="Add Login" actionListener="#{seu_bean.addNaLista()}" process="@this" update="tabelaLogin"/>
```

No seu Bean(recomendável usar o escopo `@ViewScoped` no bean):

```
public void addNaLista() {
    listaDeLogins.add(new Login());
}
```

Comment: Exatamente isso que eu quero.
Mas um nullpointexception é lançado ao clicar.
`java.lang.NullPointerException
 at net.youconnection.bean.ClienteBean.addNaLista(ClienteBean.java:61)`

Comment: Você inicializou a lista?  List<Login> listaDeLogins = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: Eu sempre esqueço desse detalhe. Obrigado @Rafael

Answer (score 1):

Vamos supor que você tenha 5 campos e quer exibi-los quando clicar em um botão ou entrar com um atalho.

No `Bean` você faz um contador, a cada clique no botão incrementa + 1. Depois no `inputText` você coloca um `rendered = "bean.contador == 1"` e assim por diante. Depois faz um botão que quando clicado pega o contador e  diminui 1.

Ficaria assim mais ou menos:

```
<p:inputText  size="40" rendered="ClienteBean.contador == 1" />
<p:inputText  size="40" rendered="ClienteBean.contador == 2" />
<p:inputText  size="40" rendered="ClienteBean.contador == 3" />
```

ClienteBean:

```
private Integer contador=0;

//Get and Set's

public void adicionaCampo(){
    contador++;
    //Adiciona elemento na lista
}

public void removeCampo(){
    contador--;
    //Remove elemento da lista
}
```

depois é só chamar esses métodos em um botão ou então em um `<p:hotkey>`.